# Implementing an ItemListener interface with an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, itemlistener

I want to execute an `ItemListener` method if a `JButton` is pressed (as written in my `ActionListener` method). I feel like I'm missing something important, because as far as I know, you cannot have method within another method.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class spelling2 extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton question1;
        JButton question2;
        private JCheckBox q1a1;
        private JCheckBox q1a2;
        private JCheckBox q1a3;


        public spelling2() {
        super("Question 1");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        q1a1 = new JCheckBox("recipracate");
        q1a2 = new JCheckBox("reciprocate");
        q1a3 = new JCheckBox("reciprokate");
        add(q1a1);
        add(q1a2);
        add(q1a3);


        question1 = new JButton("Question 1");
        add(question1);

        question2 = new JButton("Question 2");
        add(question2);


        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        q1a1.addItemListener(handler);
        q1a2.addItemListener(handler);
        q1a3.addItemListener(handler);
        question1.addActionListener(handler);
        question2.addActionListener(handler);
        }


        private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        if (question1.isSelected()) {
            d
        }
        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event) {
        if (q1a2.isSelected())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "quintessence is the correct answer");
        else if (q1a1.isSelected())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "That is the wrong answer");
        else if (q1a3.isSelected())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "That is the wrong answer");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this? `if (question1.isSelected()) { d }` Close the method brackets properly.

Comment: Done. I want the 3 check boxes to appear when one button is clicked.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 3) Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow. 4) A single blank line of white space is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my interpretation of the question is correct and you are trying to find out which of the buttons was clicked. You can use `ActionEvent.getSource()` to get the object that originated the event. For example:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == question1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "question1 is pressed");   
    } else if (event.getSource() == question2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "question2 is pressed");
    }
}
```

Note that you can also use anonymous action listeners, for example:

```
question1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "question1 is pressed");               
    }
});
```

Also note that it is usually unnecessary to extend top level windows such as JFrame unless you add new functionality to it.

Comment: I want a new window to appear with one question (3 check boxes), and after one is selected I want a new window to appear with a new question.

Comment: @Joshua I am not sure what you mean. There is nothing about it in your question. Do you want to pop up a window with a question string and three check boxes each representing a possible answer?